# CSCART: Wholesale functionality, quantity steps

Tags: e-commerce, cs-cart

Long shot here but does anyone know if CSCART can provide a customer with a trade account to only purchase products in increments of 6 while keeping it ad 1 for non trade customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can not achieve this on the same storefront.

So I see two possible solutions:

1) Use 2 different storefronts (for wholesales & retail customers) - in this case you can set separate setting values for each store. Moreover in this case you will be able to set different product descriptions/price rules etc.

2) Make a modification.

Comment: I chose the different storefront option... it was much easier.